# Grails: Pass Params from Controller to Controller at end of Webflow

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-2.0

Is it possible to pass 'params' in a redirect at the end of a Webflow? Basically the purpose of this variable or param passing from controller to controller is this, I want to have a variable or ${param.xyz} available on the view page **only** if the flow has been completed.

```
 class Example1Controller{
    def startFlow = {
        begin {
        ....
        }
        ....
        ....    
        finished {
            action {
                flash.message = 'success'
            }
            redirect(controller: 'example2', action: 'myaccount', params: [author: "Stephen King"])
        } 
     }
  }
```

OTHER CONTROLLER

```
 class Example2Controller{
     def myaccount() {
         def here = $params.author
         return [me:here]
     }
 }
```

GSP VIEW

```
 <html>
     <body>
         <g:if test="${params.me}">
             <p>This is what I want to display: **${me}**</p>
             <p>But it must come from the first controller, from the flow.</p>
         </g:if>
     </body>    
 </html>
```

Basically the purpose of all this variable passing from controller to controller is this. I want to have a variable or ${param.} available on the view page only if the flow has been completed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**hiddenField**](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/hiddenField.html) .

```
<g:hiddenField name="myField" value="myValue" />
```

you can pass value from **Example1Controller** to **Example1Gsp**(as  hideenField) and from that GSP you can get value in your **Example2Controller**.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember right, we did this before but we used the flow scope/ flow variables. Something like:

```
def myFlow = {
    fin {
        redirect: (controller: "xxx", action: "yyy", params: [someValue: flow.someValue])
    }
}
```

Then, in the receiving end, something like:

```
def yyy = {
    [ aaa: params.someValue ]
}
```